# Php mysql to json output formatting

Tags: php, json

I have my json echo  working

```
echo '{"detailsjson":'.json_encode($var).'}';
```

Now I want to write this to a file on server example output.json

I use the php code

```
 $json_data = {"detailsjson":.json_encode($var).};
 file_put_contents('output.json', $json_data);
```

i don't get the file, but for

```
file_put_contents("output.json", json_encode($var));
```

it work. I want to include detailsjson in my json so that i can get

```
{"detailsjson":[{"Name":"Amateur : Paul Smith",.....
```

Thanks

Comment: add `echo $json_data;`  before writing to file

Answer (score 2):

Your `$json_data` variable is not "valid". You have to put everything in single quotes to make it work (not in double quotes because you use them in your json). Like this:

```
$json_data = '{"detailsjson":'.json_encode($var).'}';
```

**Update (see [comment from Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568135/php-mysql-to-json-output-formatting/43568192?noredirect=1#comment74187204_43568192)):**
It is better to do this with pure arrays.

```
$json_data = json_encode(['detailsjson' => $var]);
```

You can compare them by speed [here](https://3v4l.org/EJJJb/perf#output) (using a string) and [here](https://3v4l.org/Qf3Yi/perf#output) (using pure arrays).

Comment: also it will be better to deal with pure arrays then encode your whole final array, `$array = json_encode(['detailsjson' => $var]);`